# check all values match using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Using prototype, is there a simple method of checking that a group of values match, for example - can this code be refined to a single line or something otherwise more elegant?

```
var val = null;
var fail = false;

$('form').select('.class').each(function(e){
    if(!val){
        val = $F(e);
    }else{
        if(val != $F(e)) fail = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, this oneliner should do it:

`$(form).select('.'+className).invoke('getValue').uniq().size()===1; // true means all values are the same`

- Make an array out of the values of the (input/etc) elements with the class name you are after (run `invoke` on a set of selected elements)
- Make the array contain unique values only (call `uniq` on the array)
- See if its length is 1

Links to Prototype docs:  [`Element.select`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/element/select/), [`Enumerable#invoke`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/enumerable/prototype/invoke/), [`Form.Element.getValue`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/element/getvalue/), [`Array#uniq`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/array/prototype/uniq/)

Example:

```
<body>

<form action="#" id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="foo1" class="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo2" class="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo3" class="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo4" class="foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo5" class="foo" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Returns true if all values of elements with a certain classname in the form has the same value
function bar(form, className) {
    return $(form).select('.'+className).invoke('getValue').uniq().size()===1;
}
// Usage: bar('myform', 'foo');
</script>
</body>
```